# Finding the intersection of a constrained tetrahedron and a 3D surface

Tags: geometry

Suppose I have a tetrahedron with one of its vertices constrained to move along a vertical axis and whose rotation about that axis is constrained. There is also a 3D surface which the vertical axis intersects. Thus, the tetrahedron has three degrees of freedom.

I am seeking the rotation matrix and the position of the vertex along the axis that would make the remaining three vertices of the tetrahedron lie on the 3D surface.

I can only think of iterative methods where I would start by placing the three vertices on the surface and somehow move along it to approach the vertical axis, but I don't know if there is a more elegant method. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your tetrahedron regular (all sidelengths equal)? Besides, it is not sure your problem has even a solution ? I fear you have no answer unless you give an example where the axis is the Oz axis, the surface is explicited and solutions are given.

Comment: An idea: let $D$ be the diameter of the circumscribed sphere to the tetrahedron; consider the offset surface (= "parallel surface") at distance $D$. Any intersection point (if it exists) with the axis is not far from a solution and should be a good initial point for an iterative method...

Comment: The tetrahedron is not regular, and the surface is not explicitly represented. Perhaps my problem is not well formed, and I should start with the iterative method for a good enough solution as you suggested.